# ¿Como almacenar cadenas en un CharSequence obtenidas desde un EdtiText?

Tags: android

Buenas noches mis amigos, les quiero formular una pregunta que quizá para ustedes es super sencillo, lo que deseo realizar es almacenar cadenas en un CharSequence obtenidas des un EdtiText.

Me explico al realizar clic en un botón, el valor que contenga el EditText se almacene en el CharSequence las **N** veces que se haga clic, si en el EditText escribo **manzana** luego hago clic se almacene *manzana*, después escriba **pera** y se almacena *pera*, etc.

para obtener algo similar a esto:

```
CharSequence[] frutas = {"mazana","pera", "..."};
```

Comment: Podrías ir almacenando los datos en un `ArrayList` y cuando necesites el `CharSequence` crearlo y añadir los items del anterior `ArrayList`

Comment: Me podrías referenciar donde encuentro un ejemplo

Comment: He agregado una respuesta con un sencillo ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo un ejemplo de lo que te he comentado, la idea es ir agregando los elementos en una lista, y cuando necesites el `CharSequence` convertir la lista en el array.

```
//esta lista almacenara tus string
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //añade los string a la lista
            lista.add(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    //esto convierte la lista a un CharSequence[]
    CharSequence[] charSequences = lista.toArray(new CharSequence[lista.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Excelente voy a implementarlo